# How to rebase a branch onto an indirect parent branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I branched from `master` to `feature1` and from `feature1` to `feature2`. But I actually wanted to branch both features off of `master`. I tried `git rebase master` but that just yields `Current branch feature2 is up to date.`
Why doesn't it work as I expect it to?
How can I rebase feature2 to branch off of master?

```
git init
echo "masterstuff" >> file.txt
git add file.txt && git commit -m "initial commit"
git checkout -b feature1
echo "branch1 specific" >> file.txt 
git add file.txt && git commit -m "start of feature1"
git checkout -b feature2
echo "feature2 specific" >> file.txt
git add file.txt && git commit -m "start of feature2"
```

Now I have

```
* [master] -- * [feature1] -- * [feature2]
```

and want

```
* [master] -- * [feature1]
           \- * [feature2]
```

Comment: ...and towards the above point, please include the actual branch diagrams (or representations them, at least).

Comment: Well @TimBiegeleisen the OP did give complete step by step instructions for arriving at the repo state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume exactly the "narrative" you have given:

```
git init
echo "masterstuff" >> file.txt
git add file.txt && git commit -m "initial commit"
git checkout -b feature1
echo "branch1 specific" >> file.txt 
git add file.txt && git commit -m "start of feature1"
git checkout -b feature2
echo "feature2 specific" >> file.txt
git add file.txt && git commit -m "start of feature2"
```

At the point where you leave off your "narrative", where you are still on `feature2`, you would next say:

```
git rebase --onto master feature1
```

You will then (for this particular "narrative") have a conflict to resolve! Resolve it (perhaps by editing *file.txt* manually), and then

```
git add file.txt
git rebase --continue
```

Result:

```
* 72395ff (HEAD -> feature2) start of feature2
| * b59e979 (feature1) start of feature1
|/  
* 2ab1296 (master) initial commit
```

Comment: I could explain why there is a conflict but that would take us outside the scope of the particular question. Please note that the `--onto` syntax is the real `rebase` syntax; omitting it, as you proposed to do, is a shortcut, and there are lots of circumstances (like yours) where that shortcut is not appropriate. In other words, you could and perhaps should _always_ use `--onto`; it's a little confusing at first but you'll get used to it pretty quickly.

Comment: Interesting idea to always use --onto. I think that would indeed help with clarity in understanding the --onto syntax. But do you find yourself actually typing `git rebase --onto origin/master origin/master`? :D